# PhpStorm/Symfony: Automatically import dependencies

Tags: symfony, dependencies, phpstorm

I see there is a `Ctrl+Alt+O` command in PHPStorm to import dependencies similar to `Ctrl+Shift+O` in Eclipse, but:

1. It doesn't import missing Symfony dependencies
2. Only rearranges already imported dependencies and remove duplicates (sometimes)

Is there a way to make it behave more like Eclipse for Java?

Comment: @COil Any dependency needed in the class, for example Doctrine\ORM\Mapping or Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request

Comment: @Matteo, I meant the use statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the setting you're looking for is '[Auto-Import](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/auto-import.html)'. I tend to check off both for file and namespace scope.

Alt+Enter (*nix, Windows) over a missing class will also import it if you notice while in line.

Comment: Yes I have both checked and Symfony is supported in the project

Comment: @luso Are there any issues with the project? Can you run an `app/console list` command without issue? I know some of the PhpStorm plugins depend on Symfony's cache being built out. Any major exceptions in the project cause changes not to be seen.

Comment: nope, my project runs ok, except for issues with permissions in cache and logs sometimes

Comment: @luso And this is for code you're entering after enabling that feature? Or are you wanting to go in to existing files and pull in necessary `use` statements?

Comment: no no, for example, i just added some validation asserts with @Assert\NotBlank() I would like to just Ctrl+Option+O and make PHPStorm to add the use statement for me.

Comment: @luso So this is code you're typing, then. In that case, it should be pulling that in, no add't command necessary. All out of ideas!

Comment: I mark this as accepted as it's actually the correct answer. I think I was expecting this feature to work differently. If I type the class I'm looking for, it actually updates the "use" statements. However, if I copy/paste some method, and then Ctrl+Option+o it doesn't... I will have to live whit this ;)